# What's your stance on Internet Explorer support?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Somewhat of a general question I suppose, but what's your official stance on support for previous versions of Internet Explorer?  How far do you or your colleagues actually go to insure a website looks, feels, and functions as should in Internet Explorer 8... 7... 6?...

[I remember the day Google Apps dropped support for IE7 like it was yesterday!](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9217279/Google_to_dump_support_for_Microsoft_s_IE7)  What's your stance on this?  What are the things you take into consideration before your decision is made?  Is this generally decided on a project to project basis (perhaps though evaluation of the audience)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is quite simple: While Chrome, Firefox and other browsers auto-update silently in the background, IE does not. You have to manually upgrade IE, and for companies that's a big deal of work for what the short-sighted directors think of as no gain.

Personally, I try to at least support IE7 where possible, but IE8 should be a high priority until Windows XP becomes obsolete.

Another personal preference is to list a set of browsers that the site is *intended* to work in, with links to download them, and if anyone has a different browser that happens to work then more power to them.

EDIT: Something else to consider: It's okay to not support old browsers on a new project. However, once a project already has users, be prepared to give an extremely good reason why you are forcing them to update.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it depends on the target audience for the site in question.

Most alpha geeks stopped using the old IE version long ago, so if your site targets alpha geeks only, supporting older IE versions would be a waste of time.

On the other hand, if your website is used by corporate users (who are often forced to use a particular old browser version) or, in general, people who are not likely to update their browser themselves, maybe you need to support IE 6-8 (or older versions of other browsers) as well if you don't want to risk losing users. It depends on the percentage of visitors using old browsers.